# Compare 2 cols; when 1st col > 2nd col, remove 2nd col

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk, csv

How can I compare 2 cols in csv file, divided by `,`, and cols contains quotes `"` when `,` is present in generated col, and when 2nd col > 1st col, then remove 2nd (last) col.

I did something similar, compare 2 cols and when are equal, remove 2nd (last) col.

```
awk ' BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $NF==$(NF-1){$NF=""}1 ' input_file.csv | sed 's/,$//'
```

File `input_file.csv`.

```
5,464205,Obal na zahradní topidlo ETNA,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-nabytek-zahradni-topidla-obal-na-zahradni-topidlo-etna/149210p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464205.jpg,559,559
5,464207,Obal na zahradní topidlo PYRAMIDA,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-nabytek-zahradni-topidla-obal-na-zahradni-topidlo-pyramida/149170p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464207.jpg,559,559
2,464548,Elektrický provzdušňovač combi 3 v 1 Scheppach SC 36,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-technika-sekacky-elektricke-sekacky-elektricky-provzdusnovac-combi-3-v-1-scheppach-sc-36/153943p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464548-sc36-scheppach-diy-garten-ha-kopie.jpg,2790,2790
8,465435,Plechový talíř - Autumn,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-domacnost-interierove-dekorace-ostatni-dekorace-talir-plechovy-autumn/154256p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/465435.jpg,69,39
8,466378,Proutěný věnec 30 cm - šedá,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-domacnost-interierove-dekorace-ostatni-dekorace-kruh-prouti-30cm-7-5cm-seda/154288p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/466378-kruh-prouti-30cm7-5cm-seda.png,149,159
```

Desired output, working with 2 last cols divided by `,` (just in last line is 2nd value > 1st value, `149 < 159`, so leave it, else remove last col).

```
5,464205,Obal na zahradní topidlo ETNA,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-nabytek-zahradni-topidla-obal-na-zahradni-topidlo-etna/149210p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464205.jpg,559
5,464207,Obal na zahradní topidlo PYRAMIDA,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-nabytek-zahradni-topidla-obal-na-zahradni-topidlo-pyramida/149170p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464207.jpg,559
2,464548,Elektrický provzdušňovač combi 3 v 1 Scheppach SC 36,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-technika-sekacky-elektricke-sekacky-elektricky-provzdusnovac-combi-3-v-1-scheppach-sc-36/153943p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464548-sc36-scheppach-diy-garten-ha-kopie.jpg,2790
8,465435,Plechový talíř - Autumn,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-domacnost-interierove-dekorace-ostatni-dekorace-talir-plechovy-autumn/154256p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/465435.jpg,69
8,466378,Proutěný věnec 30 cm - šedá,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-domacnost-interierove-dekorace-ostatni-dekorace-kruh-prouti-30cm-7-5cm-seda/154288p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/466378-kruh-prouti-30cm7-5cm-seda.png,149,159
```

Is possible to do it not for last col only, but for col inside somewhere in line (remove)?

And how can I do it, if quote in csv is not `"`, but `|` for example?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99396/discussion-on-question-by-genderbee-compare-2-cols-when-1st-col-2nd-col-remo).

Comment: @steeldriver Sorry, my fault, repaired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file can contain quoted embedded separators, then anything based on standard tools like `sed` or `awk` is going to be fragile - better to use a dedicated CSV parsing library.

One option is perl's [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV) module. For example, given

```
$ cat file.csv
foo,bar,baz,559,559
foo,field with spaces,baz,559,559
foo,"field with embedded, quoted separators",baz,2790,2790
foo,bar,baz,69,39
foo,bar,baz,149,159
```

then

```
$ perl -MText::CSV -lne '
  BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new()}
  @f = $p->fields() if $p->parse($_) or die "Failed to parse CSV";
  $n = $#f;
  splice @f,-1 if $f[$n] <= $f[$n-1];
  $p->print(*STDOUT,\@f)
' file.csv
foo,bar,baz,559
foo,"field with spaces",baz,559
foo,"field with embedded, quoted separators",baz,2790
foo,bar,baz,69
foo,bar,baz,149,159
```

Note that by default, the `print` method quotes fields that contain whitespace as well as those that contain the separator character - you can configure this at instantiation time by setting `quote_space` ex.:

```
  BEGIN{$p = Text::CSV->new({quote_space => 0})}
```

To make perl unicode-aware, you will likely need to add `-CSDL`. You can easily change it to compare other columns ex. `splice @f,4 if $f[4] <= $f[3]` (remembering that, in perl, arrays are zero-indexed).

---

I have a feeling that it should be much simpler to do using [miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/) by conditionally `put`ing an `unset $[NF]` however I was unable to make it work quite right.

Comment: I totally agree Miller is the right way https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178129/compare-2-cols-when-1st-col-2nd-col-remove-2nd-col/1178661#1178661

Comment: @aborruso Right - but if you use `--nidx` does it provide CSV-style quoting? otherwise it won't handle the case "*cols contains quotes " when , is present in generated col*". OTOH if you use `--csv` then it appears to insist on emitting a new header line whenever `NF` changes - even if you add `--headerless-csv-output` it appears to insert spurious blank lines. That's why I switched to perl.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), starting from

```
5,464205,Obal na zahradní topidlo ETNA,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-nabytek-zahradni-topidla-obal-na-zahradni-topidlo-etna/149210p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464205.jpg,559,559
5,464207,Obal na zahradní topidlo PYRAMIDA,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-nabytek-zahradni-topidla-obal-na-zahradni-topidlo-pyramida/149170p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464207.jpg,559,559
2,464548,Elektrický provzdušňovač combi 3 v 1 Scheppach SC 36,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-technika-sekacky-elektricke-sekacky-elektricky-provzdusnovac-combi-3-v-1-scheppach-sc-36/153943p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464548-sc36-scheppach-diy-garten-ha-kopie.jpg,2790,2790
8,465435,"Plechový, talíř - Autumn",https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-domacnost-interierove-dekorace-ostatni-dekorace-talir-plechovy-autumn/154256p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/465435.jpg,69,39
8,466378,Proutěný věnec 30 cm - šedá,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-domacnost-interierove-dekorace-ostatni-dekorace-kruh-prouti-30cm-7-5cm-seda/154288p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/466378-kruh-prouti-30cm7-5cm-seda.png,149,159
```

and running

```
mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output  put 'if ($6 >= $7) {unset $7 }' input.csv | sed -r '/^\s*$/d' >output.txt
```

you will have

```
5,464205,Obal na zahradní topidlo ETNA,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-nabytek-zahradni-topidla-obal-na-zahradni-topidlo-etna/149210p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464205.jpg,559
5,464207,Obal na zahradní topidlo PYRAMIDA,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-nabytek-zahradni-topidla-obal-na-zahradni-topidlo-pyramida/149170p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464207.jpg,559
2,464548,Elektrický provzdušňovač combi 3 v 1 Scheppach SC 36,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/zahrada-zahradni-technika-sekacky-elektricke-sekacky-elektricky-provzdusnovac-combi-3-v-1-scheppach-sc-36/153943p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/464548-sc36-scheppach-diy-garten-ha-kopie.jpg,2790
8,465435,"Plechový, talíř - Autumn",https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-domacnost-interierove-dekorace-ostatni-dekorace-talir-plechovy-autumn/154256p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/465435.jpg,69
8,466378,Proutěný věnec 30 cm - šedá,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bydleni-domacnost-interierove-dekorace-ostatni-dekorace-kruh-prouti-30cm-7-5cm-seda/154288p/?utm_source=email&utm_medium=Katalog&utm_campaign=Osvetleni_2019,https://eshop.unihobby.cz/bin/product/4/466378-kruh-prouti-30cm7-5cm-seda.png,149,159
```

If your field separator is `|` the command will be

```
mlr --csv --fs "|" --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output  put 'if ($6 >= $7) {unset $7 }' input.csv | sed -r '/^\s*$/d' >output.txt
```

If you want to compare not columns 6 and 7, you can modify the command using the column number you want to compare.